# Apple Id query on adding iphone device to Codenameone certificate generator

Tags: ios, codenameone, apple-developer

I have built my first app and wishing to get this onto my personal iPhone to test, which is where my question is.

My setup is that I have an Apple ID for home, for which the iPhone to deploy onto is connected. I have a new [company] Apple ID which I plan to register for my new Apple Developer account, so the AppStore sees my company name. 
In **Eclipse > Properties > IOS > Generate [certificate] button dialog**, you can Add Devices to a list, which can then later receive test apps (eg, through the QR Code route).

My question is specifically, can you add to this list an iPhone UDID which is registered with my Home Apple ID, ie. not registered with the Company Apple ID that is linked to the developer account? Essentially can you add anyone's device to this list?

This is important to know if I have to setup my Developer Account against my Home or new Company Apple ID in order to do the deployment.

Also FYI, there is a good tutorial document from CN1 and a good tutorial at [how-to-install-your-app-on-an-iphone](https://www.coursera.org/learn/codapps/lecture/3tgb5/how-to-install-your-app-on-an-iphone), if you needed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any iPhone UDID to the list, regardless of what device it is or who owns it. Home's, company's, personal, friend's... you name it.

Take note that you are limited to 100 test device per developer account per year and you can't remove a device once added until you renew the said account after a year (You can actually remove the device but this won't reset the counter).

Each time you add a new device, you will have to re-generate a provisioning profile only (Not the certificate) and select the devices you want to use for testing. Whenever you are asked "if you want to replace existing certificate", click **No**.

Comment: Really appreciate the response and the speed. This will help me move forward. Thanks

Comment: Only went above 15 on my Reputation 5 mins ago. Have now done it. Thanks again.